# Ставить ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

И вдруг дождь!
Нужно ли тире после "вдруг"
И почему?

Answer (score 4):

[**Из Розенталя:**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93,2#pp93)

> § 6. Тире в неполном предложении
>
> 1. **Тире ставится при наличии паузы** в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с
>      отсутствующим сказуемым)… **При отсутствии паузы тире** в эллиптическом
>      предложении **не ставится**…

.

***И вдруг (—) дождь!*** Ставить ли тире?

Постановка тире  позволяет прочитать это предложение более экспрессивно, с паузой, подчёркивающей неожиданность возникшего из ничего дождя. Автор повести [***"Слепой дождь"***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=eL8GAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD,%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85&dq=%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD,%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXiIn_1dzQAhWGdpoKHdVxDDQQ6AEIJDAA) Елизавета Максимовна Бондарева именно такое решение и выбрала.

См. контекст:

> ... а там вдали, над Жигулевским морем, угадывались рыжие стволы
>   высоченных сосен, верхушки которых кажутся черными в этот
>   ослепительный день.
>
> Но вот что-то легкое и влажное проносится над городом. **И вдруг —
>   дождь!** Да какой! Прямо с голубого неба забили косые струи, крупные
>   капли как горохом застучали по поднятому верху нашей коляски, по нашим
>   головам и спинам. И тучи нигде не видно! Вот только одна небольшая,
>   как …

Comment: В моей книге нет тире. Нет и в сборнике контрольных диктантов  для 8 класса. Это диктант по повести, там авторских знаков избегают, поэтому и исправили, но ,надеюсь, не поставили за ошибку. Должны были уловить интонацию учителя.

Answer (score 2):

Тире нужно вместо пропущенного глагола **пошёл (полил, хлынул)** дождь.

*И вдруг  ―  дождь!*

Comment: Но вот что-то легкое и влажное проносится над городом. И ВДРУГ ДОЖДЬ! Да какой!

Comment: Я сейчас делаю работу над ошибками...на уроке я так и написала  И ВДРУГ-ДОЖДЬ! мне зачеркнули тире...

Comment: Сейчас у вас получился дефис (нет пробелов), а не тире. Это можно трактовать как ошибку. Тире здесь, на мой взгляд, более вероятно, чем нет: скорее всего, здесь противопоставление ранее сказанному (напр. "было солнечно, и ничто не предвещало непогоды") и нужна риторическая пауза.

Comment: Это в напечатанном так получилось, от руки, видимо, полноценное тире, но дело не в этом, а в том, посчитали ли за ошибку, ведь оно здесь возможно как  интонационное, авторское.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение эллиптическое( с пропуском сказуемого), но восклицательное и к тому же короткое разговорной конструкции, пауза не нужна, значит, и тире не ставится. Цель автора - передать восхищение дождём, а не факт неожиданности дождя. При чтении диктанта должны были прочитать без паузы.

В общем, это на усмотрение автора, какой смысл вложит в предложение, такой будет и  пунктуация. Надеюсь, Вам ошибку не поставили, только исправили?

Answer (score 1):

Но вот что-то легкое и влажное проносится над городом. И вдруг **дождь**! Да **какой**!

**Нужно учитывать контекст предложения**. Постановка тире потребует интонационной задержки (в связи с паузой), а здесь этого не нужно, так как следующее предложение тесно связано по смыслу с предыдущим: И вдруг **дождь**, да **какой**! (как вариант). Логическое и силовое ударение на выделенных словах,  наречие "вдруг" не требует выделения.